# Mojolicious and directory traversal

Tags: perl, security, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am new to Mojolicious and trying to build a tiny webservice using this framework ,
I wrote the below code which render some file remotely

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use strict;
use warnings;



app->static->paths->[0]='C:\results';
     get '/result' => sub {

       my $self = shift;
       my $headers = $self->res->headers;
      $headers->content_type('text/zip;charset=UTF-8');

       $self->render_static('result.zip');

    };

    app->start;
```

but it seems when i try to fetch the file using the following url:

```
http://mydomain:3000/result/./../result
```

i get the file .

is there any option on mojolicious to prevent such directory traversal?

i.e in the above case i want only

```
http:/mydomain:300/result
```

to serve the page if someone  enter this url :

```
http://mydomain:3000/result/./../result
```

the page should not be served .
is it possoible to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`/$result^/` is a regular expression, and if you have not defined the scalar variable `$result` (which it does not appear you have), it resolves to `/^/`, which matches not just 
`http://mydomain:3000/result/./../result` but also
`http://mydomain:3000/john/jacob/jingleheimer/schmidt`.

`use strict` and `use warnings`, even on tiny webservices.

Comment: I am sorry before i paste my code i changed some variables names and i had typos i corrected it ,above is the case i am talking about

Comment: Sorry, i revisited the post and the code ,it mybe still some typos as english is in not my first language